# How do I run a particular version of Bootstrap in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I installed `npm install bootstrap` and then imported the file into `index.js`.

It by default runs bootstrap 5. How do I change it to Bootstrap 3? I wanted to use the blockquotes of Bootstrap 3 as its UI is better than that of bootstrap 5.